# I've problem with font in TFPDF. I can't generate pdf

Tags: php

I try generate from form pdf. And I've problem with font.
I get warning:

Warning: fseek(): stream does not support seeking in /tfpdf/font/unifont/ttfonts.php on line 165

Did anyone have a similar problem?

If so, please help.
i'm just starting programming in php.

Thank for help :)

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041875/warning-fseek-stream-does-not-support-seeking-with-fpdi

Comment: Can you show some of how you're trying to generate the PDF